# Remove mutable state and if statement

Tags: scala

Below code returns all links within a page.
The code is simplified to just expose the improvement I'm attempting to acheive.
How remove the mutable state surrounding hrefStringListBuffer & href and use idiomatic Scala ?

```
  val hrefList = List("href1" , "href2")
  val url = "testUrl"

  var hrefStringListBuffer = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]()
  for (l <- hrefList) {
    var href = getHref(l)
    if (!href.startsWith("http")) {
      href = getDomainName(url) + "/" + href
    }

    hrefStringListBuffer = hrefStringListBuffer :+ href
  }

  def getHref(str : String) = str
  def getDomainName(url : String) = url

  hrefStringListBuffer.foreach(m => println(m))
```

Something like ? :

```
val lb = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]()
  hrefList.map(m => {
      lb :+ getDomainName(m)
  })
```

But how to cater for startsWith check ?

Comment: I don't know `Scala`, but can you do a filter before the `map` ?

Comment: As a general remark concerning the second code block where you use map to append to a ListBuffer: map is used solely for its side effects, which is rather unidiomatic. Consider using a for statement or foreach instead (not in this case, but in general when you just want the side effect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the for comprehension, add `href = getHref(l)` instead of `var href = getHref(l)` (href depends on each `l`), and yield a list of `href`'s,

```
val hrefStringListBuffer =
  for (l <- hrefList; href = getHref(l)) 
  yield { 
    if (href.startsWith("http")) href
    else getDomainName(url) + "/" + href
  }
```

Also, slightly shorter than `hrefStringListBuffer.foreach(m => println(m))` is

```
hrefStringListBuffer.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `map` is all about transforming one value into another, all you care about is the return body of the `map`:

```
val lb = hrefList.map { l =>
  val href = getHref(l)
  if (href.startsWith("http"))
    href
  else
    getDomainName(url) + "/" + href
}
```

i.e. the `href` inside the body can be a `val` and you either return it or the result of the `getDomainName` construct.

Btw, the `lb` is itself an immutable `List`. No need for a mutable construct as any part of this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` over `hrefList`:

```
val hrefList: List[String] = // ...
val hrefString: List[String] = hrefList.map { l =>
  val get = getHref(l)
  if (get.startsWith("http")) {
    get
  } else {
    getDomainName(url) + "/" + get
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use map and collect:

```
hrefList.map(getHref(_)).collect{
  case elem if !elem.startsWith("http") => getDomainName(url) + "/" +  elem
  case elemWithHttp => elemWithHttp
}
```

Comment: This isn't the same - the original maintains the number of elements in the list.

Comment: As in the first part of the code we can find `if (!href.startsWith("http"))` I think we should translate that to a filter.

Comment: The original adds an element to the result list unmodified if the condition returns `false` while yours discards it.